# Xamarin iOS screenshot gets truncated when the content is wider than the frame

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to save a screenshot of a chart using xamarin. Everything is fine, except that there are times that the chart is wider than the frame, and the user needs to scroll - saving a screenshot of this gives me a truncated chart. Been scratching my head on this for almost 2 days now, below is the code. Hope anyone can point me to something.

```
UIImage image;
UIGraphics.BeginImageContext (UIScreen.MainScreen.ApplicationFrame.Size);
View.DrawViewHierarchy (View.Frame, true);
image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();
UIGraphics.EndImageContext ();
image.SaveToPhotosAlbum((img, err) => {
...
});
```

Comment: why not simply use the chart's `Frame` / `ContentSize` as the context's size instead of the main screen one's?

Comment: Hi @Krumelur I've tried that but still no luck, still getting a truncated screenshot.

Comment: Sorry forgot to that I tried: 
UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(Chart.Frame.Size);
Also tried:
Chart.DrawViewHierarchy (Chart.Frame, true);
Also tried:
UIGraphics.BeginImageContext (new SizeF(800f,800f)); 

All of the above is giving me a truncated screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

try use a function like this:

```
public UIImage SnapshotImageWithCrop (UIView view, float locHorizontal, float locVertical, float widthSize, float heightSize)
    {
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext (view.Frame.Size);
        view.DrawViewHierarchy (view.Frame, true);
        UIImage image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext ();

        UIImage croppedImage;
        using (CGImage cr = image.CGImage.WithImageInRect (new RectangleF (locHorizontal, locVertical, widthSize, heightSize))) {
            croppedImage = UIImage.FromImage (cr);
        }
        return croppedImage;
    }
```